# C compiler options passed by Mathematica

Tags: ccompilerdriver

What options can be used for compilation using `Compile` or `CreateExecutable` in Mathematica and where can one find details on the possible values for the settings?

I have a recent build of [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) installed on a Win7 workstation which works when called from the command line, but it isn't detected by Mathematica. The following should let Mathematica know where to find the compiler:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler, "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-builds\\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5\\mingw64\\bin","CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe","CompileOptions" -> "-O2"};
```

Why does the following test code (from the [specific compilers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html) help) fail to compile? I assume Mathematica is still not recognizing the C compiler, but it's not clear why.

```
In[1]:= greeter = CreateExecutable[StringJoin[
   "#include<stdio.h>\n",
   "int main(){\n",
   " printf(\"Hello MinGW-w64 world.\\n\");\n",
   "}\n"],
  "hiworld", "Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler,
  "CompilerInstallation" -> 
   "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-builds\\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5\\mingw64\\bin", 
  "CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe"]
Out[1]= $Failed
```

Setting the `"Debug"->True` for `CreateExecutable` gives us some additional output:

```
In[2]:= greeter = (*same as above, with "Debug"->True*)
```

> C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-mycomputer-1000-1000-1>C:\Program
>   Files\mingw-builds\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
>   -o
>
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-mycomputer-1000-1000-1\hiworld.exe"
>
> -g  -I"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\IncludeFiles\C" -I"C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\include"
>
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-mycomputer-1000-1000-1\hiworld.c"
>
> -L"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\lib"
>
> -L"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10 .0\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64"    2>&1
>
> C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

```
Out[2]= $Failed
```

The -L (libraries path) and -I (include path) options shown in the output are mentioned briefly in the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549505) by @Szabolcs.

Comment: Does `$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver\`MinGWCompiler\`MinGWCompiler, 
"CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-builds\\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5\\mingw64\\bin", 
"CompilerName" -> Automatic};` help?

Comment: @xzczd Do you have MinGWCompiler defined on your system? When I try with that setting I get the `CreateExecutable::badcomp` error message, which states: `Compiler specification "Compiler"->CCompilerDriver\`MinGWCompiler\`MinGWCompiler does not specify a compiler driver listed by CCompilers[Full].`

Comment: I have TDM-GCC installed in my computer. What's the output if you run `CCompilers[Full]`?

Comment: @xzczd With a fresh kernel after calling `Needs["CCompilerDriver\`"];Needs["CCompilerDriver\`GenericCCompiler\`];`, `CCompilers[Full]` returns `{{Name->Intel Compiler,Compiler->CCompilerDriver\`IntelCompiler\`IntelCompiler,CompilerInstallation->None,CompilerName->Automatic},{Name->Generic C Compiler,Compiler->GenericCCompiler,CompilerInstallation->None,CompilerName->Automatic}}`

Comment: Try : "CompilerInstallation" -> 
   "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-builds\\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5\\mingw64"

Comment: @RolfMertig I guess the `\\bin` isn't the issue. Just found a 64-bit machine and tested OP's settings, I only changed the `"CompilerInstall‌​ation"` to mine i.e. `"C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin"`, and it works well. BTW, why you think your test code failed to compile? What's the output of your `greeter`?

Comment: @xzczd and @RolfMertig, I edited the the question to include the output of `greeter`.

Comment: "**C:\Program** is not recognized……" seems that the white space in the path isn't recognized correctly. I'm not sure about the reason. Did you forget to add double quotation marks somewhere?

Comment: @xzczd Doesn't seem to help. Adding quotes to "CompilerInstallation" setting results in `$Failed` and gives the error `CreateExecutable::instl`, and there aren't any spaces or strange characters in the "CompilerName" setting. What else can be quoted or escaped?

Comment: Can it be an issue of compiler installation? Maybe quotation isn't used in some places when the compiler is installed, and it doesn't cause any problem when called from command line but does when called from _Mathematica_?

Comment: Does it work if you prefix the space in "Program Files" with a single backslash? Or maybe use `"CompilerInstallation" -> "\"C:...bin\""`?

Comment: @celtschk I'm afraid not. I've tried escaping spaces and adding escaped quotes. Just tested again to double check and no dice.

Comment: Did you try them separately?

Comment: If I purposely specify junk for the installation directory I get the error: `CreateExecutable::instl`. So I think the installation directory is being read properly either way (spaces escaped and no quotes, or everything in escaped quotes). But I'm still getting `$Failed` from `CreatExecutable` and I get the error: `Compile::nogen` from `Compile`.

Comment: Have you considered reinstalling the compiler in a directory without white spaces?

Comment: Related: [55034](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55034/mingw-64-and-compilationtarget-c-cant-make-library)