# Unable to set up Mingw-64 compiler to get CompilationTarget-"C" working

Tags: compile, installation

I am unable to set up the C compiler on my computer, thus can't not make the option `CompilationTarget-"C"` work in `Compile`. I am using windows 8 system.

At first, I install VS2013 express. `CCompilers[Full]` shows that mma has detected it.

```
{"Name" -> "Visual Studio", 
 "Compiler" -> 
  CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler, 
 "CompilerInstallation" -> 
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0", 
 "CompilerName" -> Automatic}
```

But compilation always gives errors like this

> CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: LINK : fatal
>   error LNK1104:
>   ÎÞ[CenterDot]¨.b4ò¿ªÎÄ¼þ¡[Degree]LIBCMT.lib¡[PlusMinus] >>
>
> Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled
>   function. >>

After searching, I actually didn't find any `LIBCMT.lib` file.

Then, I took advice to try to install `windows sdk`. Unfortunately, the installation failed, don't know why!!!!

Finally, according to `Specific compiler` documentation page. I tried Mingw-64. Then installation is fine. But the mma seems just can't detect it. For `CCompilers[Full]` shows

```
{"Name" -> "Generic C Compiler", 
 "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
 "CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}
```

So I run the following

```
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> 
    CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> 
    "c:/Program \
Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64", 
   "CompilerName" -> "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe"};
```

But except change the default compiler, `"CompilerInstallation"` still shows "none" and running compiled code gives errors

> Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled
>   function. >>

Need help. I really don't know how to do it right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to the Mathematica programming language.

Comment: @BobHanlon I modified my question title, maybe now it is much related to mathematica

Comment: I retracted my vote and will leave it up to others.

Comment: I would try this: First, I would make sure to install mingw in a directory with no spaces in its path. Then, I would try to `CreateLibrary` example from the documentation, making sure to set the shell command function and shell output function to `Print`, to have some idea about how Mathematica is calling the compiler and what errors the compiler might be reporting.  Also, binaries created by some versions of this compiler need additional DLLs to run.  Once compilation is successful, these may still need to be loaded with `LoadLibrary` for the library to be able to load successfully ...

Comment: Also, search this site for more MinGW-64 posts which can provide hints. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55034/12  If you solved it, please write a self-answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Following that link step by step solves my problem, many thanks, Szabolcs! Maybe my question can be deleted now.

Comment: @matheorem Do you mean Leon Avery's post?  Did you reinstall mingw in a location with no spaces in the path?  I'm asking because I'm going to have to do this myself soon ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah, I mean Leon Avery's post. I reinstall the mingw with no spaces. I should have tested it without reinstalling, but that is too late after I press the uninstall button :)  I think maybe the key is to set `path` and `library_path`, and of course `$$CCompiler`