# SetSystemOptions is obsolete? What is next？

Tags: options, implementation-details, system

When running the following code on *Mathematica* 10.2

```
SetSystemOptions[ "CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True];
```

I received the message:

> System`SetSystemOptions::obs: Developer`SetSystemOptions has been
>   superseded by System`SetSystemOptions, and is now obsolete. It will
>   not be included in future versions of the Wolfram Language. >>

What will `SetSystemOptions` become in the future?

Comment: Read the error message again. I believe it is clear. This message has been produced since at least version 7; `SetSystemOptions` moved out of the `Developer\`` context after version 5.2, which was a long time ago now.

Comment: To answer the next question, this situation was probably precipitated by your use of `<<Developer\``. Adding new contexts to the context path should be done cautiously and I would not recommend it just so that you can avoid typing the context for a few functions.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yeah! I just find this problem. I do add `<<Developer`

Comment: @OleksandrR. So you are suggesting me that if I want to use `ToPackedArray`, then I should write `Developer``ToPackedArray`, right? But I still don't understand why load `Developer`` is not right and should be done cautiously? What kind of bad things can happen?

Comment: Well, you can use `<<Developer\`` if you really want to, but you run the risk of shadowing, as you discovered with the situation here. (Shadowed symbols are highlighted in red, but maybe this is not a strong enough hint that it is a problem.) Any bad thing could happen that might result from calling the wrong function unintentionally. I don't personally add the context to the context path and I would never even consider doing it in a package or other code intended for others to use.

Comment: @OleksandrR. OK, Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Oh, one more question. Like this link says http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55037/4742   To set up a mingw-64 compiler, we need `CCompilerDriver`. If we don't load it, how can we done this?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Oh, I understand, it is the same thing. Thank you for let me know this context thing

Comment: `CCompilerDriver\`` is a package, unlike the `Developer\`` context. It is meant to be loaded this way and should not contain any shadowing symbols to begin with. This is the responsibility of the package authors, and since this is WRI, if there are any shadowing symbols then it is a bug. I just don't think it's a good idea to add arbitrary contexts to the path as if they were packages, because they are not, and thus there are no real guarantees about what they might contain.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It turns out that I did't understand at all before your comment. I should read documentations on context and packages. Thank you for your kind remind :)

Comment: @OleksandrR. Though the comment is way too long. After I read the documentations, I still got confused. First, the doc say `Developer` is also a package. As I understand it, context is just the path of package. Second, If `SetSystemOptions` really has already been moved out of `Developer`, then loading `Developer` shall not shadow `SetSystemOptions`, because there is no `SetSystemOptions` in `Developer`, only one in `System` context. So current shadowing means that there is still a `SetSystemOptions` in `Developer`, am I right?

Comment: You are right; it seems the documentation does indeed call `Developer\`` a package. Although it is not a package in the ordinary sense (the context is fully populated and so the package does not need to be loaded), with such a claim being given, it should certainly be safe to add it to the context path in this way without shadowing problems, i.e. they probably should have removed `Developer\`SetSystemOptions` some time ago. If you do not like the message, you have the option to `Off` it, or to unprotect and remove `Developer\`SystemOptions` and `Developer\`SetSystemOptions`.