# Mathematica cannot find the c compiler

Tags: compile

I installed [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138)
Then, I installed Mathematica 10 trial version.

I did:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler, 
"CompilerInstallation" -> 
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\bin", 
"CompilerName" -> "cl.exe"};

Compile[{{x}}, x^2 + Sin[x^2], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

I got:

```
CreateLibrary::badcomp: Compiler specification "Compiler" -> GenericCCompiler does not specify a compiler driver listed by CCompilers[Full]. >>

Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function. >>
```

How can I set up c compiler which I installed for Mathematica?

Comment: Do *not* set `$CCompiler`.  If the Microsoft compiler is installed correctly, Mathematica will auto-detect it. Re-start Mathematica (including the front end) after installing the compiler.

Comment: It did not work. No matter if I use `$CCompiler` or not use it, I cannot compile for c compiler. I even restarted Windows but no success.

Comment: Then the compiler is likely not properly installed.  There should be an environment variable names `VS90COMNTOOLS` or similar.  Can you check if it exists?  Evaluate `GetEnvironment[]` and look for it.

Comment: Related: [(5487)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5487/17), [(41682)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41682/17).

Comment: @Silvia One of the topics is abput visual studio 2013. I have installed 2008 edition. The other says install .Net before SDK but when Í install SDK it installs .Net too.

Comment: @yashar Sorry, I'm using 2013, so can't really help...